# How to iterate over values in SQL while performing calculations?

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I have a little complicated scenario here:

I have the following query which gives me the effect of a certain initiative on the volumes specified in the tables. If volume is 1000 and change is -500 then New Volume is 500. The same logic goes with rate. Here is the query which updates the new volume, new rate, new demand hours and new demand FTE.

```
select 
x.mdc_code, x.cal_month, x.cal_year, x.activity,  y.scenario_id, 
 y.initiative_id, x.volume, x.rate, y.metric_to_be_applied, y.change,

CASE WHEN y.metric_to_be_applied = 'Volume'
THEN x.volume + y.change end as New_Volume_VolumeChange ,
CASE WHEN y.metric_to_be_applied = 'Volume'
THEN x.rate end as New_Rate_VolumeChange,
CASE WHEN y.metric_to_be_applied = 'Volume'
THEN (x.volume + y.change)/x.rate end as New_DemandHours_VolumeChange,
CASE WHEN y.metric_to_be_applied = 'Volume'
THEN ((x.volume + y.change)/x.rate)/176 end as New_DemandFTE_VolumeChange,
CASE WHEN y.metric_to_be_applied = 'Rate'
THEN x.volume end as New_Volume_RateChange ,
CASE WHEN y.metric_to_be_applied = 'Rate'
THEN x.rate + y.change end as New_Rate_RateChange,
CASE WHEN y.metric_to_be_applied = 'Rate'
THEN (x.volume)/(x.rate + y.change) end as New_DemandHours_RateChange,
CASE WHEN y.metric_to_be_applied = 'Rate'
THEN ((x.volume)/(x.rate+ y.change))/176 end as New_DemandFTE_RateChange
from
(SELECT  [id] as activity_id
  ,[mdc_code]
  ,[function_name]
  ,[cal_month]
  ,[cal_year]
  ,[model_type]
  ,[activity]
  ,[activity_type]
  ,[product_category]
  ,[project_category]
  ,[segment]
  ,[volume]
  ,[demand_fte]
  ,[demand_hours]
  ,[rate]
  ,[sub_division_name]
  ,[division_name]
  ,[myp_year]
  ,[client_count]
  ,[calls]
  ,[loguser]
  ,[logdate]
  ,[IsProd]
  ,[version_id]
FROM [myp_activity]
)x

join

(
SELECT [id]
  ,[scenario_id]
  ,[initiative_id]
  ,[initiative_name]
  ,[comments]
  ,[recommended_by]
  ,[mdc_code]
  ,[function_name]
  ,[cal_month]
  ,[cal_year]
  ,[model_type]
  ,[activity]
  ,[metric_to_be_applied]
  ,[change_type]
  ,[change]
  ,[sub_division_name]
  ,[division_name]
  ,[myp_year]
  ,[loguser]
  ,[logdate]
  ,[IsProd]
  ,[version_id]
  ,[initiative_type]
  FROM [myp_initiatives] where initiative_id=10001
 ) y
on x.mdc_code = y.mdc_code
and x.cal_month = y.cal_month
and x.cal_year = y.cal_year
and x.activity = y.activity
```

I have the following output for this query:

[image]

There are 4 more columns which are not listed in the picture(New_Volume_RateChange, New_Rate_RateChange, New_DemandHours_RateChange, New_DemandFTE_RateChange).

I need to apply initiative 10002 on this data. Details of initiative 10002 are present in the the initiatives table which has been used for joining. Right now the output has initiative 10001 applied on it.
For example:
If Initiative 10001 has Volume listed in one of the rows as 500 and Initiative 2 has change as -300, then the output should have 200 as the Volume column listed in that particular row.
Also, initiative_id should be changed to 10002 from 10001 as the initiative 10002 is the initiative which was applied last.

Again if we have Initiative 10003 listed which is to be applied on Initiative 10002 then the output should list 10003 as the initiative.

Hence Initiatives 10002, 10003 and so on should be applied on my data which has been generated from the above query.

In all of these cases the joining criteria of two tables (initiatives and activity) will be the same as listed in the query.

How do I achieve this?

I had tried a CTE but was unable to do it. I am confused about how to perform the calculations (CASE WHEN statements) on that.

Comment: Am I to understand that your calculating a series of initiatives? That is, 10001 *and then* 10002 onto the 10001 results *and then* 10003 results onto the combined 10001 and 10002 results?

Comment: Is there a fixed number of initiatives...or are there lots of them?

Comment: And...are all the intermediate results to be shown? Or are we only interested in the final applied initiative?

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is a great place to start.

Comment: @Clay I do not need to show intermediate results. And yes, 10002 is applied on 10001 to give me a new dataset on which 10003 will be applied.

Comment: That's as I surmised...and answered that way ;-)

Comment: @Clay I am unable to see your answer! Did you remove it?

Comment: I'm working on a different version of it

Comment: Okay, Thank You! That query was working fine, but I was just a bit puzzled seeing the different number of rows that it was generating. Also, apologies for the delayed response!

Comment: Hey @Clay, any progress on the query? I seem to have made an error in the last query that was shared and even that is not working :-( Can you please help?

Comment: @AsheshDas - See if that doesn't work a little better for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

This is pretty much a complete rewrite of the answer I had before

Still, as mentioned earlier, I'd lose all the brackets...they just make your code that much more unreadable. You really only need them when a column name conflicts with a reserved word in SQL.

Next, you don't have to `select` from a `select` to alias...and you don't have to worry about getting extra data in the intermediate results. You should really only `select` from a `select` when you're doing some kind of aggregations or calculations. A great example would be your `y`...where you can calculate the base factor for your calculations...and then get rid of the `CASE`s entirely...like this:

```
select 
  x.mdc_code, x.cal_month, x.cal_year, x.activity,  y.scenario_id, 
  y.initiative_id, x.volume, x.rate, y.metric_to_be_applied, y.change,

  x.volume + applied_volume as New_Volume_VolumeChange ,
  x.rate * applied_volume as New_Rate_VolumeChange,
  (x.volume + applied_volume)/x.rate as New_DemandHours_VolumeChange,
  ((x.volume + applied_volume)/x.rate)/176 as New_DemandFTE_VolumeChange,
  x.volume + applied_rate as New_Volume_RateChange ,
  x.rate * applied_rate as New_Rate_RateChange,
  (x.volume)/(x.rate + applied_rate) as New_DemandHours_RateChange,
  ((x.volume)/(x.rate+ applied_rate))/176 as New_DemandFTE_RateChange
from
  myp_activity x
  inner join
  ( select 
      iif( metric_to_be_applied = 'Volume', change, null ) as applied_volume,
      iif( metric_to_be_applied = 'Rate', change, null ) as applied_rate,
      mdc_code, cal_month, cal_year, activity, scenario_id, initiative_id, metric_to_be_applied, change
    from 
      myp_initiatives
  ) as y
on 
    x.mdc_code = y.mdc_code
    and x.cal_month = y.cal_month
    and x.cal_year = y.cal_year
    and x.activity = y.activity
where 
  y.initiative_id=10001
```

Conceptually, this is totally appropriate, however, the requirements you have mean a simple CTE can't be applied to the problem...as far as I can tell. This is because there's no way to iterate over the initiatives that I can work out. Instead, let me offer a function which will aggregate the changes the way you need (I think).

However, notice something important. I don't know the data types of your columns, and so this function declares everything as `int` which *I'm sure* isn't right. You'll have to edit the data types to match what you *really* have.

```
create function AppliedInitiatives() returns  
@t table
( 
  mdc_code int, --> note: you have to change all these types to match your data
  cal_month int, 
  cal_year int, 
  cal_activity int, 
  scenario_id int,
  initiative_id int,
  volume int,
  rate int,
  metric_to_be_applied nvarchar( 32 ),
  change int,
  New_Volume_VolumeChange int,
  New_Rate_VolumeChange int,
  New_DemandHours_VolumeChange int,
  New_DemandFTE_VolumeChange int,
  New_Volume_RateChange int,
  New_Rate_RateChange int,
  New_DemandHours_RateChange int,
  New_DemandFTE_RateChange int
) as 
begin

  declare
    @applied_volume int, --> note: you have to change all these types to match your data
    @applied_rate int,
    @mdc_code int, 
    @cal_month int, 
    @cal_year int, 
    @cal_activity int, 
    @scenario_id int,
    @initiative_id int,
    @previous_initiative_id int,
    @volume int,
    @rate int,
    @metric_to_be_applied nvarchar( 32 ),
    @change int

  declare c cursor for 
  select 
    iif( metric_to_be_applied = 'Volume', change, null ) as applied_volume,
    iif( metric_to_be_applied = 'Rate', change, null ) as applied_rate,
    mdc_code, cal_month, cal_year, activity, scenario_id, initiative_id, metric_to_be_applied, change
  from 
    myp_initiatives
  order by
    initiative_id;

   open c
   while ( 1 = 1 )
   begin
    fetch next from c into
      @applied_volume,
      @applied_rate,
      @mdc_code, 
      @cal_month, 
      @cal_year, 
      @cal_activity, 
      @scenario_id,
      @initiative_id,
      @metric_to_be_applied,
      @change
      if ( @@fetch_status != 0 ) break

     if ( @previous_initiative_id is null )
     begin
      insert @t select
        @mdc_code, @cal_month, @cal_year, @cal_activity,  @scenario_id, 
        @initiative_id, @volume, @rate, @metric_to_be_applied, @change,

        x.volume + @applied_volume                as New_Volume_VolumeChange ,
        x.rate * @applied_volume                  as New_Rate_VolumeChange,
        (x.volume + @applied_volume)/x.rate       as New_DemandHours_VolumeChange,
        ((x.volume + @applied_volume)/x.rate)/176 as New_DemandFTE_VolumeChange,
        x.volume + @applied_rate                  as New_Volume_RateChange ,
        x.rate * @applied_rate                    as New_Rate_RateChange,
        (x.volume)/(x.rate + @applied_rate)       as New_DemandHours_RateChange,
        ((x.volume)/(x.rate+ @applied_rate))/176  as New_DemandFTE_RateChange
      from
        myp_activity x
      where
        x.mdc_code = @mdc_code
        and x.cal_month = @cal_month
        and x.cal_year = @cal_year
        and x.activity = @cal_activity
      select @previous_initiative_id = @initiative_id
    end
    else
    begin
      insert @t select
        @mdc_code, @cal_month, @cal_year, @cal_activity,  @scenario_id, 
        @initiative_id, @volume, @rate, @metric_to_be_applied, @change,

        New_Volume_VolumeChange + @applied_volume                               as New_Volume_VolumeChange ,
        New_Rate_VolumeChange * @applied_volume                                 as New_Rate_VolumeChange,
        (New_Volume_VolumeChange + @applied_volume)/New_Rate_VolumeChange       as New_DemandHours_VolumeChange,
        ((New_Volume_VolumeChange + @applied_volume)/New_Rate_VolumeChange)/176 as New_DemandFTE_VolumeChange,
        New_Volume_VolumeChange + @applied_rate                                 as New_Volume_RateChange ,
        New_Rate_VolumeChange * @applied_rate                                   as New_Rate_RateChange,
        (New_Volume_VolumeChange)/(New_Rate_VolumeChange + @applied_rate)       as New_DemandHours_RateChange,
        ((New_Volume_VolumeChange)/(New_Rate_VolumeChange+ @applied_rate))/176  as New_DemandFTE_RateChange
      from
        @t x
      where
        x.mdc_code = @mdc_code
        and x.cal_month = @cal_month
        and x.cal_year = @cal_year
        and x.cal_activity = @cal_activity
        and x.initiative_id = @previous_initiative_id
      select @previous_initiative_id = @initiative_id
    end  
  end

  return 

end
```

What's going on here is that the function starts by writing the first set of values into the table `@t`, and then inserts updated values by applying the results to each *previous initiative* and writing those into `@t`. At the end, it returns the table.

Once you've defined this function, you can just say:

```
select
  * --> note: would be better to list columns...but I'm being lazy for clarity
from
  AppliedInitiatives()
```

If somebody could rewrite this as a cte, it would be a learning experience for me, too!

Comment: I am getting the following error : "Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "mdc_code" of recursive query "base"." Any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: Yeah...I did a typo in the second part (the recursive part)...should have been x.mdc_code, x.cal_month, x.cal_year, x.activity the select list...have fixed it

Comment: @AsheshDas I updated the code...let me know how you do with it.

Comment: Hi Clay, When I execute this CTE for initiative_id = 10002, the number of rows increase from 336 to 2688. Any idea why this happens? Also the new volume when initiative 10002 is applied should be = (the new volume for initiative 10001) + (change in 10002) and the initiative_id displayed in the output should be 10002. How do I incorporate that?

Comment: After changing the data types and executing the function I am getting a "Divide by zero error encountered." error. Any idea how can I avoid this?

Comment: You're going to have to work that out based on your data. Sometimes, when you divide...and then divide again...etc... you can reduce a denominator to 0. You'll have to guard for that...maybe going from `.../expr` to `.../(iif(expr=0,0.000001,expr))`. It's entirely data- and calculation-dependent.

Comment: Ok I will try that and update you once I am able to get the output

Comment: this was really helpful. It served mu purpose. Thank You so much!

Answer (score 0):

While you may or may not get an answer including a modified version of your code, you may want to look at the simplified query below to understand one way to address the "running values" problem you have.

```
DECLARE @Initiative TABLE (IntiativeID INT, AddToValue INT, Code NVARCHAR(10))
DECLARE @Data TABLE(DataID INT, Value INT, Code NVARCHAR(10))

INSERT @Data VALUES(1,10,'A'),(2,10,'B'),(3,10,'A')
INSERT @Initiative VALUES(1,5,'A'),(2,5,'A'),(4,5,'B'),(800,5,'C'),(24,5,'D')


SELECT 
    DataId,
    StartValue = Value,
    LastIntiativeID = MAX(IntiativeID),
    EndValue = Value + SUM(AddToValue)
FROM 
    @Data D 
    LEFT JOIN  @Initiative I ON D.Code = I.Code
GROUP BY 
    DataID,Value
ORDER BY
    DataID
```